# How to manage object that need to know things about themselves that belong to a upper context?

Tags: oop

Image a game where you have a board and that board is made of multiple cells (tiles, call them whatever you like).

We have two classes, `Board` and `Cell`. Board has a 2D array of Cells.

How to handle the fact that each cell knows things about itself (how to be drawn on the screen, if it's walkable by the playing character and so on) with the fact that some of those informations are only known to an upper level (like known by Board)? For example, a cell should also know where it is (x, y coordinates) but storing that information both on the Cell (like x and y properties) and on the Board (as indexes in the array) is redundant. Also, for example, it would be useful for the Cell to know its neighbours.

What is a good OOP design in these cases?

Comment: Abstraction will be useful na? Board can contain the common functions and cells can use the highlevel functions of Board and can define their own functions  like getNeighbourDetails.

Answer (score 1):

Do not store redundant information on both classes. I think that both classes should stand as is, if you described the whole story.

`Board` should contain the `Cell` array you said, which will keep the information you are mentioning (coordinates) and will provide them to *public* with getter functions. Something like this:

```
class Board {
  private:
    Cell array[N][M];
  ..
};

class Cell {
  public:
    int getX() { return x; }
    int getY() { return y; }
    ...
  private:
    int x;
    int y;
    ...
};
```

Of course you could make them *friends*, but I wouldn't doing so, except something serious with I/O came up.

Maybe, you should start thinking of **inheritance** too, since some information is shared. In that case, `Board` has access to the data members it needs to, without the `Cell` class having to provide getter functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Board as an Abstract class and Cell can use the functions of Board without knowing in detail and at the same time it can define its own functions.

Comment: But he will want to have an object of class `Board` I think. :/